# Как вывести конкретный элемент массива в laravel?

Tags: php, массивы, laravel

Помогите мне вывести конкретный элемент массива в  Laravel 5.4

Короче, вот роуты (web.php)

```
Route::name('admin::')->prefix('admin')->group(function(){
//Авторизация
Route::name('auth::')->prefix('auth')->group(function(){
    Route::name('view')->get('view', 'Admin\DashboardController@auth');
    Route::name('act')->post('act', 'Admin\DashboardController@auth');
    Route::name('logout')->get('logout', 'Admin\DashboardController@logout');
});

Route::name('home')->get('home', 'Admin\DashboardController@home');

Route::name('content::')->prefix('content')->group(function(){


    Route::name('page::')->prefix('page')->group(function(){
        Route::name('list')->get('list', 'Admin\DashboardController@list');
        Route::name('about')->get('about', 'Admin\DashboardController@about');
```

Метод в контроллере (DashboardController@about)

```
    public function about()
{
    return view('upgr.static.about', [
        'dashboards' => Dashboard::orderBy('id')->paginate(16),
        'dashboard' => [],
        'delimiter' => ''
    ]);
}
```

Сам файл about

```
@section('content')

<main>
    <div class="container">
        <ol class="breadcrumbs">
            <li class="breadcrumbs-item"><a href="/">Главная</a></li>
            @forelse($dashboards as $dashboard)
                <li class="breadcrumbs-item">{{ $dashboard->name }}</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{ $dashboard->title }}</h1>
        <p>{!! $dashboard->description !!}</p>
        <img src="{{ $dashboard->image }}" alt="{{ $dashboard->name}}" class="img-responsive">
        @empty
            <h2>Скоро здесь появиться информация, пожалуйста подождите.</h2>
        @endforelse
    </div>
</main>

@endsection
```

При таком раскладе у меня на сайте само собой выводятся все данные из бд[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сори все, кому глаза режет мой вопрос)

По моим предположениям вместо цикла нужно поставить условие и поменять первую строку в контроллере, но что я не пытался сделать - не выходит.

Вопрос в том как мне сделать так, чтобы на вкладке "О компании" выводились данные с id = 2, на "Контакты" id = 3 и т. д. ?

---

P. s. Я поменял метод в контроллере на

```
    public function about()
{
    return view('upgr.static.about', [
        'dashboard' => Dashboard::orderBy('id')->get()->first(),
        'delimiter' => ''
    ]);
}

public function kontakt()
{
    return view('upgr.static.kontakt', [
        'dashboard' => Dashboard::orderBy('id')->get()->first(),
        'delimiter' => ''
    ]);
}
```

Также поменял два файла about и kontakt

about.blade.php:

```
@section('content')

<main>
    <div class="container">
        <ol class="breadcrumbs">
            <li class="breadcrumbs-item"><a href="/">Главная</a></li>
            @if($dashboard['id'] == 2)
                <li class="breadcrumbs-item">{{ $dashboard->name }}</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{ $dashboard->title }}</h1>
        <p>{!! $dashboard->description !!}</p>
        <img src="{{ $dashboard->image }}" alt="{{ $dashboard->name}}" class="img-responsive">
        @endif
    </div>
</main>

@endsection
```

показывает вот что, все окей, я так и хотел [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

kontakt.blade.php

```
@section('content')
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <ol class="breadcrumbs">
            <li class="breadcrumbs-item"><a href="/">Главная</a></li>
            @if($dashboard['id'] == 3)
            <li class="breadcrumbs-item">{{ $dashboard->name }}</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="container">       

        <h1>{{ $dashboard->title }}</h1>

        <p>{!! $dashboard->description !!}</p>

        <br><br><br>
        @endif
    </div>
</main>

@endsection
```

ничего не показывает [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему? Все идентично и казалось бы поменял id должна вывестись другая инфа из бд, нет?

Comment: Глаза режет не вопрос а цвет кода, ярко зеленый на черном фоне X_X

Comment: @Manitikyl от настроек монитора может зависеть. но в любом случае код - текстом надо а не картинками

Comment: Извиняюсь, на следующий раз учту. И кодом сейчас отредактирую.

Comment: @teran у меня обычный монитор как и у всех, не думаю что кто-то сидел и выкручивал себе зеленый, чтобы потом в редакторе сделать поярче, чтобы нормально видеть код.

Comment: я и не говорю что кто-то выкручивал зеленый. это скорее одна из стандартных схем, которая вкупе с подуставшим монитором и плохим зрением автора возможно ему вполне комфортна.

Comment: Надеюсь теперь будет понятнее.

Comment: @teran как-то странно монитор устает, зеленый нужен прям яркий, а бледно-оранжевый на темном фоне - нормально))

Comment: @Manitikyl я, наверное, поставлю точку в вашей дискуссии: мне просто нравится ярко-зеленый цвет)) Монитор настроен у меня хорошо, зрение единичка)

Comment: Сначала очистите кэш вьюшек через php artisan view:clear, и сделайте  'dashboard' => Dashboard::orderBy('id')->get()->first() вместо []

Comment: @DanielProtopopov
Если поменять dashboard - ничего не произойдет.
Если поменять dashboards, то появится ошибка Trying to get property of non-object (View: .../views/upgr/static/about.blade.php)

Comment: Не понятно про какие данные вы говорите, @Sepol - у вас пока что список dashboards и dashboard отдельно, использовал это как пример. Во вьюшке у вас никакого вывода данных нет, только dashboards/dashboard, поэтому и порекомендовал вам использовать dashboard, а не dashboards

Comment: Так, есть небольшой сдвиг, смотреть P.s.

Comment: У вас данные для страницы находятся в dashboard, попробуйте 'dashboard' => Dashboard::find(3) для about страницы.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Ты мой герой! Спасибо тебе огромное! Ответь не в комментах, а на вопрос,чтобы я мог поставить тебе плюсик к карме и к репутации)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас данные для страницы находятся в dashboard, попробуйте

```
'dashboard' => Dashboard::find(3)
```

для about страницы. Тройку нужно будет в каждом контроллере заменить на нужный ID раздела.